# Collection Of Open Nonempty Sets.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

**How do I show that every family of open nonempty disjoint sets (in $\mathbb{R}$) is countable?**

I think I should use the fact that every nonempty open set is the disjoint union of a countable collection of open intervals, but I'm not sure.
The question here is pretty simple but I can't even start to think of a way to solve it.

Comment: Open sets in which space?  If you mean open sets in $\Bbb R^n$ with the usual topology, then show that any non-empty open sets contain a point all of whose coordinates are rational numbers.

Comment: Hint: Using axiom of choice for every element of a family $\{U\}$ of open nonempty disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, there exists an injective map $f:\{U\}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(U)\in U$.

Answer (score 1):

More generally:

> **Lemma.** Assume that $X$ is a topological space and $D\subseteq X$ is a dense subset. Then any family of open, pairwise disjoint subsets of $X$ has cardinality at most $|D|$.

*Proof.* Let $\mathcal{U}$ be a family of open, pairwise disjoint subsets. Since $D$ is dense then $D\cap U\neq\emptyset$ for any $U\in\mathcal{U}$. Thus by the Axiom of Choice there is a function $f:\mathcal{U}\to D$ such that $f(U)\in U$. This function is injective because $\mathcal{U}$ contains pairwise disjoint subsets. Therefore $|\mathcal{U}|\leq |D|$. $\Box$

Now just apply the lemma to $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $D=\mathbb{Q}$.