# Are there uncountably many pairwise disjoint open intervals of $(a,b)?$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R},$ and let $a<b.$ Are there uncountably many pairwise disjoint open intervals of $I=(a,b)?$ I know that the answer is no since if there were uncountably many pairwise disjoint open intervals of $I,$ then, from the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R},$ we would get that each of these intervals would have atleast one rational in them implying that $\mathbb{Q}$ is uncountable. I am looking for a different proof, though.

Comment: Why would you need a different proof?

Comment: @Arthur, I just want a different way of seeing this.

Comment: The answer is obviously "yes": take the singletons. You are probably meaning "non-trivial subintervals", not just "subsets".

Comment: Are you asking about _subsets_ or _open subsets_?

Comment: @AnneBauval, edited, please check.

Comment: @BrianMoehring, I'm asking about intervals (I edited the question).

Comment: "Intervals" is not sufficient. Singletons are (closed) intervals.

Comment: @AnneBauval, open intervals, then. Sorry, I'm new to analysis.

Comment: This [very FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=disjoint+open+intervals+is+countable) always has [the same answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3385355): the one you don't want.

Comment: @AnneBauval, then I guess I'm stuck with this proof for now. I'll delete the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $\sum_{i\in F} a_i$ is finite then $a_i =0$ except for countably many $i\in F$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814966/if-sum-i-in-f-a-i-is-finite-then-a-i-0-except-for-countably-many-i-in-f) (apply it on the lengths of your intervals)